# Re-activate the new Gmail compose

Tags: gmail

After my first toying around with the new Gmail compose I clicked on the button that said 'I want to keep using the old compose' or something similar with the same meaning.

Now I want to try it again, but I don't find any option to reactivate the new Gmail compose.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you deactivated the new compose feature, your Gmail should have refreshed.

To get it back, just click `Compose`, and you should see a message at the top that says "Try out the new compose experience" Clicking this will refresh the page again with the new compose feature enabled.

Comment: Nope, there's no link to re-enable it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I would get the option on `Reply` as well. It is *only* if you click `Compose`. Got it now.